# go mod vendors older version of dependency

Tags: go, dependencies

I upgraded to go1.11 and i am trying to use go modules. I cloned a project and ran `go build` which creates a `go.mod` and `go.sum` files with all my dependencies.

Now i would like to vendor the files so i run the command `go mod vendor`

Unfortunately go mod vendors an older version of [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata). My project is unable to build because a function call does not exist. Looking at the source code of the vendored `go-bindata` i can see that it is different from what is available in the master branch of `go-bindata` project.

In my `go.mod` file there's this:

```
github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata v3.0.7+incompatible
```

In my `go.sum` file, there's this:

```
github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata v3.0.7+incompatible h1:91Uy4d9SYVr1kyTJ15wJsog+esAZZl7JmEfTkwmhJts=
github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata v3.0.7+incompatible/go.mod h1:JVvhzYOiGBnFSYRyV00iY8q7/0PThjIYav1p9h5dmKs=
```

On GitHub, the most recent tag for `go-bindata` is v3.0.7 on the master branch.

Any ideas why `go mod` references an older version and how can i fix that. On a different machine, running `go get -u https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata` gets the most up to date project. Why does `go mod` not do the same?

EDIT:
The problem is that `go mod` says it got v3.0.7 but the source code doesn't match what is currently available on Github with the 3.0.7 tag. What i have locally looks like v3.0.6 but is tagged as v3.0.7.

In the version on Github, there is a struct that looks like this:
[link to source](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/blob/6025e8de665b31fa74ab1a66f2cddd8c0abf887e/config.go#L131)

```
type Config struct {
     //... some other fields
     NoMetadata bool
}
```

But in my local vendored version, the Config struct doesn't have `NoMetadata` field. 
It looks like `go mod` is using an older tag and thinks it's using the most recent.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent tag for that repo is v3.0.7, so that's what `go mod` gets you. From [the FAQ](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-a-module-consume-a-package-that-has-not-opted-in-to-modules):

> If a repository has not opted in to modules but has been tagged with
>   valid semver tags (including the required leading v), then those
>   semver tags can be used in a go get, and a corresponding semver
>   version will be record in the importing module's go.mod file.

Is the issue that you want code that's not in the 3.0.7 tag, but is in the master branch?

---

Looking at the specific `NoMetadata` field in your update, it was added in https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/commit/7f4fb1184ff6bab28016ed674b61864665ba3d97, on 2015-08-13. Meanwhile, v3.0.7 was tagged on 2014-11-20

So it seems like the changes you're interested in are not tagged and are only on the master branch.

Given this situation you could just fork the repository - it hasn't been maintained since 2015 (and the README acknowledges it's unmaintainted). Or find something that's being kept up-to-date. Or convince the maintainers to create a new tag.

Comment: Hi. I just edited my post so you could see what the issue is. If you want to reproduce it, i am trying to make this project "https://github.com/qor/qor-example/" build.

Comment: `go get` downloads the project and puts the dependency in `$GOPATH/src/github/jteeuwen/go-bindata`. Is there a way to build my project where this particular dependency is gotten from my gopath?

Comment: @SomeGuyFortune: I'm not sure, sorry. Given the state of that repo, it will be troublesome to use it (the latest version) with go modules. Keep in mind that go modules are quickly becoming a standard built into the tools. Since that repo seems abandoned, if you must absolutely use it I'd just vendor it manually into my project's own src and be done with it (this means just creating a `bindata` dir somewhere and placing the package's latest code in it, with the proper license etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of `go` I guess. Use hash code of commit in `go.mod` file to get exact version of branch.

When you run `go mod vendor` hash code in `go.mod` will be replaced with correct version and `vendor` directory will have necessary code.

before:

```
replace github.com/example-project/example-app/go/v3 => github.com/example-project/example-app/go/v3 952d4033cffcf7ed10de054f6f80547bcd9b45f9
```

after:

```
replace github.com/example-project/example-app/go/v3 => github.com/example-project/example-app/go/v3 v3.8.2-0.20210812190102-1f3470d253d3
```